# List of included graphics with full pathname

Tags: graphics, directory

Is there a way to get a list of all used graphics with full pathnames? The problem is that I have set the `$TEXINPUTS` variable pointing to a directory containing images (which I included just using the filename), but I have also images included from the current directory and from some directories above (via `../image.png`).

I tried the snapshot package but this gives me only the filenames without the complete path.

Answer (score 2):

Many TeX compilers (pdfTeX, luaTeX, XeTeX) have an option `-recorder`, which behaves independent of the output mode (DVI, PDF). It records the input and output files in the file name `<jobname>.fls`.

Example:

```
% test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

Compilation: `pdflatex -recorder test`

Then `test.fls` contains the absolute path of the image (`grep INPUT test.fls|sort|uniq|grep png`):

```
INPUT /absolute-path-to/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.png
```

Answer (score 1):

This will output at the end of the log file the list of included graphic files, with the full path unless the image file is called with a relative path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xparse}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Gin@setfile}
  {\@addtofilelist{#3}}
  {\@addtofilelist{#3}\studentaddtoiglist{#3}}
  {}{\ddt}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\studentaddtoiglist}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_student_ig_filename_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l_student_ig_filename_tl { } { "|kpsewhich~\l_student_ig_filename_tl" }
  \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_student_ig_files_tl { \l_student_ig_filename_tl ^^J }
 }
\AtEndDocument{\typeout{\g_student_ig_files_tl}}
\tl_new:N \l_student_ig_filename_tl
\tl_new:N \g_student_ig_files_tl
\tl_gset:Nn \g_student_ig_files_tl { ***~Graphic~files~*** ^^J }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{../curva}

\includegraphics{example-image}

\includegraphics{brave-gnu-world-logo}

\end{document}
```

I ran this with

```
TEXINPUTS=/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/images/: pdflatex mwe
```

so the variable `TEXINPUTS` is set for the specific job; it would be the same if it is set in the environment; in that case, just `pdflatex mwe` would suffice.

Here's the relevant part of the log file

```
*** Graphic files ***
../curva.jpg
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.png 
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/images/brave-gnu-world-logo.jpg
```

Note that the last file wouldn't be found without setting `TEXINPUTS`.